# How to store complex data structures in MySQL and prevent duplicates?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures, object-model

MySQL 5.5

I am writing a system for storing queries.

Every time a person submits a search, it can be saved in the database. There can be additional actions connected to the search.

I.e. "look for rows where color=red or color=blue and change color_type to 'primary color'"

My problem is, because of the number of tables involved, there is nothing preventing the same query from being saved twice.

The essential part of the query is the query itself, rather than the action attached.

For example, if someone happens to enter the same query as above but using the action "change color_hue to 90%", their action should be attached to the previous search.

As of now, it would create a duplicate search.

Of course, this would all be easy if it was saved in a single table with indexes, but it's not.

I have:

```
search_terms
id | search_terms (varchar 255 UNIQUE)

searches
id | table_to_search

search_groups
id | search_id (FK to searches.id) | search_terms_id (FK to search_terms.id) | search_exclude (bool)

`search_exclude` determines whether to match the terms or exclude them.

target_fields
id | field_name

search_groups_target_fields (linking table for many-to-many relationship between search_groups and target_fields)
search_group_id (FK1) | target_field_id (FK2)
(composite unique index on FK1+FK2)
```

So how can I enforce uniqueness of these searches, when the facts of each search are located in 3 different tables?

Each search can have many search groups. And each search group can have many fields and vice versa.

I also thought of this potential change, taking the search_id FK out of search groups and putting it in a linking table, allowing many-to-many searches-to-groups.

```
search_groups
id |  search_terms_id (FK to search_terms.id) | search_exclude (bool)

searches_search_groups
search_id (FK) | search_group_id (FK)
```

But now `search_groups` doesn't look much different than `search_terms`. Except that each group is still defined by its component fields. The core question of this is, how can I make sure each group is unique when its definition is partly composed by the contents of a different table? I don't think it's possible with indexes.

Comment: It's not possible with just indexes.  It's possible with application code.

Comment: Would you consider having a command line wrapper on these searches as in that case you have very rigid control on the searches...and find duplicate searches easily and dont have to do sql matching to find duplicate searches

Comment: @bapusethi It's actually a PHP application.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am using PHP. So I suppose I would want to start a transaction and/or lock tables, do a few queries and then take action based on those... I think I'll probably post an answer to my own question. it's complex, but might be useful to someone else.